# HTML Input Values clear when post back

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, input

I created two input box  and set javascript for auto focus next box when reach max length.It is working properly.but when fire any post back event these vaules getting clear.I put runat="server" on Input box then values clear issues fixed but auto focus script not working. Pls help me.

```js
function movetoNext(current, nextFieldID) {
 if (current.value.length >= current.maxLength) {
  document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtcard1" size="4" 
  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'txtcard2')" maxlength="4" />
  
<input type="text" id="txtcard2" size="4" 
  onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'txtcard3')" maxlength="4"   />
```

Comment: Can you add more code in roder to show how you fixed the "input box clear" issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question details seems your using ASP.net.

You must have to Add `runat="server"` to maintain control state, but at same time when you add `runat="server"`  then control will render at sever and ID of control will be changed.

So, you need `ClientIDMode="Static"` Tag while using control at Client side script.

For E.g:

```
<input type="text" id="txtcard2" size="4" 
        onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'txtcard3')" maxlength="4"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"  />
```

Comment: It is working property now .Thank you for your help.I have to changed  ClientIDMode to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

But if you're using an older version it won't work as the autofocus attribute is new to HTML5 which only gained broad support in recent brwser

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Control.ClientID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the ASPX Control ID at client-side. With this, the control will be available at both server and client side.

```
<input type="text" id="txtcard1" size="4" runat="server"
        onkeyup="movetoNext(this, '<%= txtcard2.ClientID %>')" maxlength="4" />

<input type="text" id="txtcard2" size="4" runat="server"
        onkeyup="movetoNext(this, '<%= txtcard3.ClientID %>')" maxlength="4"   />
```

Also not sure with your requirement, but if you want to move to the controls in your form then use [tabindex](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)